# Solution for diagonal design (background-img) overlay and transitions

Tags: svg, background-image, overlay, transition, diagonal

As I'm trying to get my skills to the next level, I've been thinking of the best way to solve this and haven't really found an option. For our clients, we often use designs that involve diagonal images as transition or overlay from one content field to another.
What I mean is stuff like this

[image: diagnoal and curvy background svg]

[image: hexagon overlay]

What we usually do is export the whole image (as for option one) and use it as a background-image, which affects the performance in a really negative way.
As I don't want to use huge images but still want to keep the image clean (not pixelated), I'm asking what kind of solution is there to keep the img size small for loading reasons and also provide an easy way to adjust it for responsive design.

I'm thankful for any advice and help!